# Drag and Drop *FROM* a browser?

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Dragging items **into** a browser is pretty well documented, and HTML5 makes this easier.

However, I'm wondering if and how it's possible to drag 'n' drop **out of** a browser.

In this scenario, you'd have a webpage element (eg. an anchor) that the user would click & drag *OUT* of the browser onto a drop target, and the browser would send the linked object (eg. an href'd file) directly to the drop target instead of starting the usual download.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: No, it's definitely not.

Comment: @woz: I'm pretty sure it actually is. Try dragging a link to a .mp3 file or something, won't it download the file to that location? Or would it simply create a link on your desktop?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It doesn't work for me. Drag-and-drop to from a website to your computer would be such a big security issue that I doubt it will ever be implemented.

Comment: You can drag and drop from a browser, however what is does depends on the browser used. In some browsers, dragging and dropping a link to the desktop will copy the file to the computer.

Comment: I just tried with Firefox: dragging a link: it creates a shortcut. Dragging a picture: it copies the picture to the computer.

Comment: Though this has been a couple years, I'm wondering if you ever got it working cross-browser. Chrome seems to handle it fine, but FF not so much.

Comment: I just tried with @dichambers profile picture.  It just works (TM) with Chrome and Safari on Macbook Pro.  It does not do anything (TM) with Firefox on Macbook Pro.  On IE11 on a Windows 7 VM, it works, but it asks me questions before allowing the drop and then I think it creates a link rather than copying the picture itself.

Comment: @emory you just wanted my picture ;)

Comment: @dlchambers that's the price you pay for being so handsome :)

Answer (score 12):

The very thing you are trying to do can be found here: https://ryanseddon.com/html5/gmail-dragout/.

This is an explanation for how to drag an anchor tag to the desktop, and the file will be downloaded there.  (Or drag the anchor tag onto another application, and the OS will treat it appropriately.)

What I haven't figured out yet, is how to drag-and-drop multiple links (instead of only one at a time) via HTML5, without having to resort to an external resource library like jquery.

Comment: It was Dropbox that brought me to this question. I noticed that using the web app it's possible to drag individual files out, but not highlight multiple files then download them all out. This disappointed me. I can't think how it would be done though. Could jQuery intercept this somehow and send each files' link to the OS individually (i.e. one after the other)? I could very well encounter a similar requirement in a web app I'm working on.

Comment: @RyanWilliams you could generate a link which includes the IDs of each file, and perform a download event for a single file, which is essentially a zip of each selected file in a single package. I don't believe you can create multiple downloads from the single event (I've not tried it though, but plan on doing the zip method myself).

Comment: This article is great, however, what if you want to do this in a local environment. I have a local Angular2/Node app that monitors storage. I want to drag and drop a file from my web GUI into another application. This almost seems like it would work, except its actually transferring the file, I just want to transfer a symlink. Anyone ever see that?

Comment: Dragging multiple images from browser to Word is possible: Select html with portion of multiple images, drag to MS Word -> all there. Not sure if that can be used generally for "files", unless they are embedded in HTML somehow.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually Yes, this is possible. But it would be the OS/application handling the drop to decide what to do with it. In fact you can do exactly what you describe with chrome. Open a new chrome window and drag a link to it. It navigates there. Drag a link to your desktop. In Win7 it creates a shortcut/link to that page.

What you are talking about is not HTML drag and drop but actually at an OS/application level. And would have to be handled with an application language, not the browser HTML.